# How do you cast Eyes of the Hawk?

Tags: talisman

The card says to cast it after rolling for the move, but I can't figure out how to actually do so.

After rolling the move, if I select the spell, I do get an option to *Queue* (or *De-Queue*) it. But it doesn't appear to actually get cast.

Comment: Is it just this spell giving you issues or others as well?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Just that one, altough I didn't end up laying the game for long. Talisman is... not a good game and digitalization isn't enough to save it.

Comment: Sorry you didn't enjoy it, different needs, though. As a parent, I like it as a game that doesn't require full concentration and the digitization means fewer pieces to lose or end up in a kid's mouth.

Comment: One more question, did you have the Amulet or were you on the Hidden Grove?